# Компиляция проекта TypeScript в один файл

Tags: typescript

Есть следующий код на TypeScript:

```
class A {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    constructor() {
        this.a = 'str1';
        this.b = 20;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    c: string;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.c = 'str2';
    }
}

var a: B = new B;

console.log(a);
```

Компиляцию могу запускать и напрямую через "tsc", и при помощи сборщика, все работает нормально. Следующий шаг - хочу разделить классы, записав их в разных модулях.

Модуль a.ts:

```
export class A {
    a: string;
    b: number;

    constructor() {
        this.a = 'str1';
        this.b = 20;
    }
}
```

Модуль index.ts:

```
import {A} from './a';

class B extends A {
    c: string;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.c = 'str2';
    }
}

var a: B = new B;

console.log(a);
```

Тут и начинаются проблемы. При компиляции "tsc" в браузере выдается ошибка:

> exports is not defined

При использовании сборщика - если хочу скомпилировать результат в один файл, то ставлю в "tsconfig.json" параметр "module": "system" - появляется такая ошибка:

> System is not defined

Если ставлю "module": "amd" - ошибка такая:

> define is not defined

Если ставлю "module": "commonjs", то параметра "outFile" он уже не воспринимает, компилирует все ts-файлы отдельно. При подключении этих файлов к проекту браузер выдает следующую ошибку:

> exports is not defined

Подскажите правильную последовательность действий. Желательно настроить сборку проекта в один js-файл, чтобы не подключать каждый модуль в html отдельно.

Comment: Посмотри в сторону webpack

Comment: Вопрос №1:
Будешь ли ты импортировать __сторонние__ модули по типу реакт?

Варианты ответа:
- Да
- Нет
- Да, буду подключать в html скриптом

Comment: @qwabra, будет один сторонний модуль, который подключается через `html`. На `TypeScript` будет написана довольно объемная программа (потому этот язык и выбран), и хотелось бы иметь возможность распределять код по модулям, которые бы автоматически компилировались и объединялись в `js`-файл.

Comment: (#1)есть вариант с использованием родного компилятора(`tsc`) в режиме `"module": "None"` - относительно чистый способ, когда файлы "склеиваются в один" почти как есть (#2)Eсть различные варианты с различными сборщиками

Comment: @nup, налево или направо ?)

Comment: @qwabra нужно будет попробовать первый вариант для этой задачи. Подскажите, если говорим о системе модулей, когда они помещаются в объект, а не просто склеиваются - это реализовано для разделения области видимости переменных или для чего-то еще?

Comment: по поводу модулей - начни с этого: https://learn.javascript.ru/modules. По поводу "попробовать" попробуй и отпишись - если что, я набросаю ответ с примером.